# Strange behaviour in ActiveRecord finder while using SQL condition IN

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a table called `inbox_messages` with following rows:

```
user_id message_id
======= ==========
4       8
4       1
4       7
0       9
0       10
0       11
0       12
```

The table maps to the following model:

```
class InboxMessage < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

When I invoke the `find` method with a `IN` caluse, I get different resultset depending on the position 
of the parameters.

```
InboxMessage.find(:all, :conditions => [ "user_id IN (?)", "0,4"]) # 8 rows
InboxMessage.find(:all, :conditions => [ "user_id IN (?)", "4,0"]) # 3 rows
```

Second call above, returns 3 rows instead of 8. Other scenarios works fine, i.e.

```
InboxMessage.find(:all, :conditions => [ "user_id IN (0, 4)" ]) # 8 rows
InboxMessage.find(:all, :conditions => [ "user_id IN (4, 0)" ]) # 8 rows
InboxMessage.find(:all, :conditions => [ :user_id => [0, 4]  ]) # 8 rows
InboxMessage.find(:all, :conditions => [ :user_id => [4, 0]  ]) # 8 rows
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the literal is being passed into the SQL statement as a single literal.

```
InboxMessage.find(:all, :conditions => [ "user_id IN (?)", "0,4"])
becomes Select ... WHERE (user_id IN ('4,0'))
```

Try using two substitutions and it will work as you expect

```
InboxMessage.find(:all, :conditions => [ "user_id IN (?, ?)", 0,4])
becomes Select ... WHERE (user_id IN (4,0))
```

You can see what the actual SQL statement is by looking at the log in development mode.

Comment: I think you are right. Confusion was due to the fact that I got the expected results when I changed the bind parameter order. I managed to see the SQL and it is erroneous(as you noted). (PS: I used the "SQL_DISPLAY":http://github.com/radar/sql_display plugin to list the SQL)

Answer (score 0):

This is a different form which I prefer to use because I find it more readable:

```
InboxMessage.find_all_by_user_id([0,4])
```

Comment: I have multiple parameters in my `find` call. I simplified the sample code for easier read.